# objectify - java.lang.IllegalStateException: At path ** Expected property value

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have a below entity containing an EmbedMap, which in turn contains an Embed object.

```
@Entity
public class Data
{
    @Id private long id;
    private String name;
    @EmbedMap Map<String, PlayerData> dataMap = Maps.newHashMap();
}

@Embed
public class PlayerData
{
    private long playerId;
    List<TurnData> turns = Lists.newArrayList();
}

@Embed
public class TurnData
{
    private long turnId;
    private long score;
}
```

When I try to save the Data entity into **datastore** using **Objectify**, I get the below exception (I am currently on objectify **4.0b3**):

com.googlecode.objectify.impl.cmd.SaverImpl.entity(SaverImpl.java:33) at test.BattleResponseTest.populateBattlesData(BattleResponseTest.java:172) at test.BattleResponseTest.testGetAllBattles_checkBattleIds(BattleResponseTest.java:185) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45) at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: At path 'dataMap.1.turns': Expected property value, got {turnId={1},  score={135000}} at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Path.throwIllegalState(Path.java:134) at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.populateFields(Transmog.java:402) at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.populateFields(Transmog.java:430) at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.populateFields(Transmog.java:430) at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.populateFields(Transmog.java:430) at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.save(Transmog.java:364) at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.save(Transmog.java:100) ... 30 more

Kindly help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format Objectify v4 uses to store embedded collections does not accommodate storing collections nested inside of collections. If you migrate to v5, you will be able to do this.